# Enumerate list using recursion, python

Tags: python, list, recursion, enumerate

I'm trying to enumerate the list using recursion and am having a hard time doing so.
If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
def my_enumerate(items, start_index=0):
    """my enumerate"""
    
    result = []
    if not items:
        return []
    else:
        a = (start_index, items[0])
        result.append(a)
        my_enumerate(items[1:], start_index + 1)
    return result 
        
ans = my_enumerate([10, 20, 30])
print(ans)**strong text**
```

Comment: To get the output you're expecting, you need to add the output of `my_enumerate` into the `result` list: `result += my_enumerate(items[1:], start_index + 1)`

Comment: The idea of a recursive `enumerate()` is fine just for practicing recursion, just want to make sure that you're aware that it's not a practical idea for normal use, and will limit you to lists smaller than max recursion depth

Comment: No it's an exercise for my 2nd year paper! thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
def my_enumerate(items, start_index=0):
    """my enumerate"""
    
    result = []
    if not items:
        return []
    else:
        a = (start_index, items[0])
        result.append(a)
        result += my_enumerate(items[1:], start_index + 1)  # here
    return result
```

The following is more concise:

```py
def my_enumerate(items, start_index=0):
    """my enumerate"""
    return [(start_index, items[0])] + my_enumerate(items[1:], start_index + 1) if items else []
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using recursion and you are declaring `result = []` within a function so everytime it simply gets empty so you lose all previous results.

If you want exactly this to work there is also another way that by making the result as **global** if you wanted to use that list globally like below:

```
result = []

def my_enumerate(items, start_index=0):
    """my enumerate"""
    
    global result    
    if not items:
        return []
    else:
        a = (start_index, items[0])
        result.append(a)
        my_enumerate(items[1:], start_index + 1)
    return result 
        
ans = my_enumerate([10, 20, 30])
print(and)
```

But @CocompleteHippopotamus answer will work when you don't want to use a global keyword.